# Do I have to create a new SCRIPT tag every time I am making a call with JSONP?

Tags: javascript, json, dom, jsonp

I am calling my database via HTTP. Since it is not on the same server as my application I am using JSONP. So everytime I want to query information from my database my JavaScript function adds another script tag to the DOM tree. When my application is running for a while the source code is flooded with SCRIPT tags.

Is that just something I have to accept working with JSONP or is there another way around?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to go about doing that.  Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's just a problem with JSONP. You can attach an `onload` handler to the `script` element to clean it up when it's done (`onreadystatechange` for IE).

Or, since you control both servers, you can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). This is less of a hack than JSONP, and offers the flexibility of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser, but generally, yes.  You do have to add a new script tag.  However, you can remove the script dom element after the script is loaded.  If you are using jQuery, it takes care of this for you - the method you need to use to do this is somewhat browser dependent.

If you are using Visual Studio, even though the script is being removed, you will still see a reference to the script in the debugger.  As far as I can tell, in a production mode, this does not mean that there is a "leak".

Comment: Yes. jQuery handles this for you and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

When I receive a JSONP response I remove the `script` tag. For example:

```
function makeJSONPRequest() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var callbackName = 'callback' + (+new Date()) + '_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://www.example.com/jsonp?callback=' + callbackName;
    window[callbackName] = callback;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    function callback(data) {
        delete window[callbackName];
        document.head.removeChild(script), script = null;
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```